# PowerMockito 1.6.0 verify private final overloaded methods in the Mockito Extension API

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, powermock

couple of days ago new version of PowerMockito has been released with support to verify private/protected method calls. Although I made it work in simple case, I am missing something with more "complicated" function. Given the following classes:

```
public class A {

    protected void myMethod(Exception... ex) {
        System.out.println("Method A");
    }

    protected void another() {
        System.out.println("Method A 1");
    }
}
```

:

```
public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected void myMethod(Exception... ex) {
        System.out.println("Method B");
    }

    @Override
    protected void another() {
        System.out.println("Method B 1");
    }
}
```

:

```
public class C extends B {

    @Override
    protected void myMethod(Exception... ex) {
        System.out.println("Method C");
    }

    public void testMe() {
        myMethod(new NullPointerException("XXX"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void another() {
        System.out.println("Method C 1");
    }

    public void testMeAnother() {
        another();
    }
}
```

and the following test case:

```
@PrepareForTest({ A.class, B.class, C.class })
public class MethodTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        C classUnderTest = PowerMockito.mock(C.class);

        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(classUnderTest, "testMeAnother");
        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(classUnderTest, "testMe");
        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(classUnderTest, "myMethod");
        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(classUnderTest, "another");

        classUnderTest.testMeAnother();
        classUnderTest.testMe();

        //this works as expected
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(classUnderTest, times(1))
            .invoke(PowerMockito.method(C.class, "another"))
            .withNoArguments();

        //this raises an TooManymethodsFoundException:
        // Matching:
        // void myMethod(...)
        // void myMethod(...)
        // void myMethod(...)
        // three times!
        PowerMockito
            .verifyPrivate(classUnderTest, times(1))
            .invoke(PowerMockito.method(C.class, "myMethod",
            Exception[].class))
            .withArguments(any(Exception[].class));
    }
}
```

//yes, I am calling the methods on mock directly, no matter for this snippet

Full stack strace of given test can be found [there](http://wklej.to/4XF9d)

Thanks in advance!